# array_slice - how come this doesn't work in foreach

Tags: php

total noob here. I've an array which looks like:

```
Array
(
    [15] => Array
      (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 5216
                [name] => Grow your own Irish Shamrock gifts set
                [ordered] => 473
                [image] => FunShamrockPot.jpg
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 5217
                [name] => Irish Shamrock Seeds
                [ordered] => 357
                [image] => FunShamrockSeed.jpg
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 5759
                [name] => Ireland Fleece with Shamrock Badge
                [ordered] => 1
                [image] => IrelandFleeceShamrocks.jpg
            )

    )

    [31] => Array
      (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 5081
                [name] => Tartan Guinness Flat Cap
                [ordered] => 356
                [image] => GuinnessTartanFlatCap.jpg
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 4894
                [name] => Black signature emblem Guinness baseball hat
                [ordered] => 176
                [image] => GuinnessSigBBHat.jpg
            )
```

The array is called $products and I'm trying to just print out the first five arrays in each top array (if that makes sense) in other words, array[15]<-- first five arrays under 15, array[31]<-- first 5 arrays in here.

the code I'm trying is:

```
foreach($products as $key=>$value) {
    array_slice($value, 0, 5);
    foreach($value as $product) {
        echo $product['name'] . '<br/>';
    }
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

I can't figure out why array_slice won't work, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `array_slice` does not modify the input array, you need the return value:

```
foreach($products as $key=>$value) {
    $sliced = array_slice($value, 0, 5);
    foreach($sliced as $product) {
        echo $product['name'] . '<br/>';
    }
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($products as $key=>$value) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach($value as $product) {
        if($i <5) {
        echo $product['name'] . '<br/>';
        $i++;
        } else {
        break;
        }
    }
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

**edit to answer why array_slice didnt work**

you would need to have done

```
$newarray = array_slice($value, 0, 5);
    foreach($newarray as $product) {
    echo $product['name'] . '<br/>';
}
```